Using a list objects operations interfere with Lifecycle rules?
If I perform a list_objects, list_objects_v2 operation, or a bucket.objects.all(), or any kind of listing operation in S3, can I interfere with lifecycle rules?
I'm afraid I can move a file in glacier to an standard storage class again.

Listing objects will not make your files move to a standard storage class.
If you use regular tiers (standard, IA, Glacier...) and use lifecycle rules to move them around, lifecycle rules only look at the creation date of the object. Additionally, lifecycle rules only move objects "down" (Standard->IA->Glacier) and cannot move objects the other way around.
On the other hand, if you use the intelligent tier, it moves objects both ways, but in that case, listing still doesn't affect the tier. Actions that count as access to the object (and thus affect the tier) are:

Downloading or copying an object through the Amazon S3 console.
Invoking CopyObject, UploadPartCopy, or replicating objects with Batch Replication. In these cases, the source objects of the copy or replication operations are tiered up.
Invoking GetObject, PutObject, RestoreObject, CompleteMultipartUpload, or ListParts.

This list was taken from the documentation
